# Why does the first section element seem to be included in the nth-child sibling count?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm specifically targeting the nth-child(2n), but the first, third, etc of sibling with the given class is having the css applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/relitnosmoge/9HCnH/1/

```css
.grid > section.fifty:nth-child(2n) {
        background: red !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<article class="block grid">
    <section class="block hundred"></section>
    <section class="block fifty"></section>
    <section class="block fifty"></section>
    <section class="block fifty"></section>
    <section class="block fifty"></section>
</article>
```

Comment: Those indexes are 1 based not zero based

Comment: Is there anyway to target a chosen index (say 3) of a specific class reliably using css, regardless of the total elements? Also, why are all siblings included in the index, regardless of whether or not they're part of the targeted class?

Comment: Well the selector is nth- **child** not nth-child-tageret

Comment: Is there a psuedo selector that would all you to target an element/class, with only those elements/classes making up the index, regardless of the total/absolute index?

Comment: nth-of-type seems to behave in a similar way, the sibling index including all siblings, not just the ones satisfying the selector as defined? Or do I need to more specifically target the given class(es)? I've attempted that approach, but it didn't seem to improve the results.

Comment: `.fifty` and `:nth-of-type(2n)` is equal in priority, which measn `section:nth-of-type(2n).fifty` is the same as `section.fifty:nth-of-type(2n)`. And I think that's true for all selectors unless CSS allow you to use parenthesis. So your request doesn't seem to be able to archive.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
nth-child(even)
```

or

```
nth-child(2n+2)
```

will work I guess. Can you please try that out ?

Using this with your class i.e. fifty will select only class fifty and not hundred.

Comment: nth-child(even) selects the same siblings as nth-child(2n) because all of the sections are included in the total sibling count (or index). As I understand it at least. The only problem with 2n+2 is that I need a way to select a specific interval of a given class regardless of the siblings within the 'grid' parent. 2n+1 only works in this given instance.